# Help standardise decimals and change orders of magnitude in siunitx table

Tags: siunitx, threeparttable

I have a badly written table that has a variable figures after the decimal. I also want to shift the order of magnitude by a factor of 3. The original table is quite big, but this MWE captures some of the ways in which the values are expressed.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

Please help to standardise the decimals (express all up to two significant figures after the decimal point) and shift orders of magnitude (from \unit{\micro\gram\per\milli\litre} to \unit{\milli\gram\per\milli\litre}).

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Values are expressed in \unit{\micro\gram\per\milli\litre}}
\begin{tabular}{l S S}
\toprule
\textbf{Samples} & \textbf{Conc 1} & \textbf{Conc 2} \\
\midrule
Sample 1 & 3562.26±12.5 & 12156±0.2 \\
Sample 2 & 0.15±0 & 1568.8984±12.5 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The output looks a bit like this:

[image: Output1]

However, I want the output to look something like this:

[image: Ideal_image]